# Deserialize JSON array to string array with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON array to a string list with:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result) as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray;
List<string> response = jsonResponse.ToObject<List<string>>();
```

The JSON has the following structure:

> [["No Es Posible Importar Dos Numeros De Servicios Iguales","No Es
>   Posible Importar Dos Codigos Iguales"]]

But that throws the following error:

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path '[0]'.

How I can deserialize the object without errors?

Comment: why does your json start with two `[[`?  did you intend to have an array inside an array?

Comment: It's a nested, jagged array so do `var lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>(result)`.  There's no need for the intermediate `JArray` representation by the way.

Comment: @Claies i dont now, im receiving the string from a web service, when i put this in a JSON viewer works fine

Comment: it's a list of lists of strings, so you either need to use the option @dbc mentioned, or `List<List<string>> response = jsonResponse.ToObject<List<List<string>>>()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks!!!

i followed the recommendations in the comments and all is working fine.

i only changed the code to:

```
var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(result);
```

to get a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:-

`var list = JArray.Parse(@"[[""a"", ""b"", ""c""]]").Values().Select(x => x.Value<string>()).ToList();`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had spent some time working on this with a *C# Fiddle* (I love these for collaboration) while you got it running locally, but I took your solution and put it into a fiddle so that some others later might have complete code that runs and they can play with.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/mAU6gi

Additionally this highlights the need to include, and has the nuget packages needed readily available on the page!

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

This also then shows a user how to enumerate their new nested list and display all of the values in the order they came in from the JSON.

**Thanks!**
-App-Devon